# Linux C programing

Tags: c, linux, struct, pthreads, named-pipes

Its the 1st time im making a question here , so i hope im not making any mistakes...
Im doing a server-client program and i have this error when i run client, i have "core dumped error".

I think i know where is the error but i dont know how to solve it.
I have 2 structs :

```
typedef struct {
    int pid;
    int cmd; //1 -login,2-registrar,3-tecla
    char login[100];
    char pw[100];
    int tecla;
} PEDIDO;

typedef struct {
    int cmd;
    int res;
    BONECO *b;
} RESPOSTA;
```

Code when server sends data to client through a named pipe :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){
//...
     i = read(fd, &p, sizeof (p));
                    printf(">>> Li %d bytes\n", i);
                    printf("User : %s PID : %d\n", p.login, p.pid);
                    if (p.cmd == 1) { //LOGIN

                        char user_fd[100], pw_fd[100];
                        FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
                        if (!f) {
                            printf("Erro ao abrir ficheiro\n");
                            exit(0);
                        }
                        while ((fscanf(f, "%s %s ", user_fd, pw_fd))) {
                            if (strcmp(p.login, user_fd) == 0 && strcmp(p.pw,pw_fd) == 0) {
                                printf("\nLOGIN CORRECTO!!!\n");
                                for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                                    if (clientes[i][0] != p.pid && clientes[i][0] == -1) {
                                        clientes[i][0] = p.pid;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                sprintf(cli_fifo, "ccc%d", p.pid);
                                fd_resp = open(cli_fifo, O_WRONLY);
                                r.cmd = 1;
                                r.res = 1;
                                i = write(fd_resp, &r, sizeof (r));
                                close(fd_resp);
                                fclose(f);
                                break;
                            }

//...

}
```

Code of client to receive data from server :

```
void *recebe_msg(void *dados) {
    int i;
    sprintf(cli_fifo, "ccc%d", getpid());
    mkfifo(cli_fifo, 0600);
    fd_resp = open(cli_fifo, O_RDWR);
    menu();
    do {
        i = read(fd_resp, &r, sizeof (r));
        if (ESTADO == 0) {
            if (r.cmd == 1 && r.res == 1) { // OK
                ESTADO = 1;
                wclear(win);
                mvwprintw(win, 10, 14, "Login efectuado com sucesso!");

                wprintw(win, "BONECO %d, %d , %d , %d ",r.b[0].num,r.b[0].humano,r.b[0].remate,r.b[0].tempo);

                wrefresh(win);
                sleep(3);
                desenha_campo();
            }
            if (r.cmd == 1 && r.res == 0) { // NOK
                wclear(win);
                mvwprintw(win, 10, 14, "Senha e/ou login incorrectos!!!");
                wrefresh(win);
                sleep(3);
                menu();
            }
            if (r.cmd == 2 && r.res == 0) {
                wclear(win);
                mvwprintw(win, 10, 14, "Login já está em uso!");
                wrefresh(win);
                sleep(3);
                menu();
            }
            if (r.cmd == 2 && r.res == 1) {
                wclear(win);
                mvwprintw(win, 10, 14, "Registo efectuado com sucesso!");
                wrefresh(win);
                sleep(3);
                menu();
            }

            if (r.cmd == 9) { // sair
                FIM = 1;
            }
        } else if (ESTADO == 1 || ESTADO == 2) {
            wclear(win3);
            scrollok(win3, TRUE);
            keypad(win3, TRUE);
            noecho();
            if (r.cmd == 3) { // actualizacao de jogadores
                desenha_campo();
                desenha_jogadores();
            } else if (r.cmd == 9) { // sair
                FIM = 1;
            }
        }
    } while (!FIM);

    close(fd_resp);
    unlink(cli_fifo);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

OBS: I think the error is on the 3rd field of struct RESPOSTA, but i dont know how to solve it

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO community! Please, post definition of every variable and struct (you refer struct BONECO, but not posted it's declaration). Also, compile your code with option -ggdb and then run your code under gdb. When you got segmentation fault, use command "bt" and post it here. Good luck!

Comment: typedef struct {
    int humano; // pid
    int posXant, posYant; // posicao anterior
    int posX, posY; // posicao destino no ecra
    int num; // numJog
    int tempo; //vel
    int remate;
    int equipa;
} BONECO;

Comment: Okay, my assumption turned out to be true, I created answer. Also, what this program will do?

Answer (score 1):

Here you read BONECO structure:

```
    i = read(fd_resp, &r, sizeof (r));
```

Please note, BONECO is declared as pointer, NOT ACTUAL DATA.

But here you try to read this data:

```
    wprintw(win, "BONECO %d, %d , %d , %d ",r.b[0].num,r.b[0].humano,r.b[0].remate,r.b[0].tempo);
```

While you try to access r.b[0], you get segmentation fault, as you try to dereference b pointer, which point to... Unknown location. This cause error just as planned.

I suggest to modify your struct to:

```
typedef struct {
    int cmd;
    int res;
    int count_of_boneco;
    BONECO b[];
} RESPOSTA;
```

If you allocate sufficiently large buffer, you can read all your data and then dereference at you do it now.

Comment: Yes it worked but the client dont receive data of  "RESPOSTA.b".
It comes empty

Comment: Fix your server logic to new structure layout